# Android Mapview Out of Memory Exception

Tags: android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

I have a mapview in my app and whenever the user do too much zoom-in or out the mapview crashes. Following is the data allocation I got from DDMS just when the crash happened:

```
486 17971   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
422 17966   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
349 17963   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
244 17958   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
172 17935   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
102 17886   byte[]  1   com.google.common.io.android.AndroidPersistentStore readBlock   
96  9526    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
64  9526    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
481 9268    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
462 9268    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
345 9058    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
289 9058    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
418 8994    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
400 8994    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
236 8808    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
164 8421    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
92  8351    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
479 8076    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
416 7779    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
240 7682    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
219 7682    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
166 7468    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
147 7468    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
342 7415    byte[]  1   com.google.googlenav.map.MapTile    read    
15  4920    long[]  22  com.google.googlenav.map.MapService
```

I have only one overlay i.e custom overlay

public class ProfilesOverlay extends Overlay {

```
private static final String TAG="ProfilesOverlay";

private Paint paintCircle;
private Paint paintText;
private  Bitmap heartIcon;
boolean multitouchGesture;
boolean showCounts;

public interface ProfilesOverlayDelegate {
    public List<OverlayInfo> getOverlayInfo();
    public void onOverlayTouched();
    public boolean onOverlayTapped(GeoPoint p);
}

ProfilesOverlayDelegate delegate;


public ProfilesOverlay(ProfilesOverlayDelegate delegate, Resources res, boolean showCounts) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.showCounts = showCounts;


    paintCircle = new Paint();
    paintCircle.setColor(res.getColor(R.color.mapProfileClusterCircle));
    paintCircle.setAntiAlias(true);

        heartIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.flirtplace_white);

    paintText = new Paint();
    paintText.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paintText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    paintText.setTextSize((float)(heartIcon.getHeight() * 0.7));
    paintText.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override 
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView map, boolean shadow) {

        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        Point point = new Point();
        int heartWidth = heartIcon.getWidth();
        int heartHeight = heartIcon.getHeight();

        for (OverlayInfo overlay : delegate.getOverlayInfo()) {
            projection.toPixels(overlay.getGeoPoint(), point);

            if(isLocationVisible(point,map)){       

                paintCircle.setAlpha(overlay.getAlphs());
                canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, (int) overlay.getRadius(), paintCircle);
                canvas.drawBitmap(heartIcon, point.x - heartWidth/2, point.y - heartHeight / 2, null);

                if(showCounts) {
                    canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(overlay.getCount()), point.x + heartWidth - App.dp(6), point.y + App.dp(4), paintText);
                }

            }    

    }

        super.draw(canvas, map, shadow);
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView map) {
    multitouchGesture = event.getPointerCount()>1;
    delegate.onOverlayTouched();    
    return super.onTouchEvent(event, map);
}

@Override
public boolean  onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView map) {
    if (multitouchGesture) {
        return false; // 
    }
    return delegate.onOverlayTapped(p);
}


//check if given location is visible on the screen
private boolean isLocationVisible(Point point, MapView mapView)
{
    Rect currentMapBoundsRect = new Rect();
    mapView.getDrawingRect(currentMapBoundsRect);
    return currentMapBoundsRect.contains(point.x, point.y);

}
```

}

And I am using it in my activity as :

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.getOverlays().add(new ProfilesOverlay(this, activity.getResources(), true));
```

Stack Trace very common:

```
06-13 17:27:49.479: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(20267): 584640-byte external allocation too large for this process.
06-13 17:27:49.479: ERROR/dalvikvm(20267): Out of memory: Heap Size=10339KB, Allocated=9989KB, Bitmap Size=14057KB, Limit=21884KB
06-13 17:27:49.479: ERROR/dalvikvm(20267): Trim info: Footprint=11335KB, Allowed Footprint=11335KB, Trimmed=996KB
06-13 17:27:49.479: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(20267): VM won't let us allocate 584640 bytes
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:677)
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.createSnapshot(ZoomHelper.java:444)
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.google.android.maps.ZoomHelper.beginZoom(ZoomHelper.java:194)
06-13 17:27:49.479: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$2.onScaleBegin(MapView.java:371)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ScaleGestureDetector.java:248)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:646)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3778)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:919)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:958)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1716)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1124)
06-13 17:27:49.489: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2125)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1700)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1802)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-13 17:27:49.499: WARN/System.err(20267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: And the code that causes the crash?

Comment: Did you find any solution? The same is happening to me.

Comment: No solution, Map API in Android require quite a bit of memory. If your application have any leaks maps will crash your app. So the problem is not the map API try using MAT to find and fix memory leaks. It should solve the problem